# kubernetes で pod の作成と更新を自動化したい

Tags: kubernetes

kubernetes を使用しております。
GitHub から docker build して docker hub にアップロードするところは自前で用意できます。
しかし、pod の作成と更新を自動化したいのですが、どのようなツールがありますか？
例えば Circle CI はどうでしょうか？

または k8s ライブラリを使用して、pod を更新することは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

私はGitLab + Jenkins + ArgoCDを利用して自動でPod作成,更新できるよう構築しました。
CircleCIでも同じことができるはずなので、可能かと思います。

私は以下のように構築しています。

Jenkinsジョブにて以下3点実施

1. docker build
2. docker hubへのアップロード
3. GitLabで管理しているマニフェストのイメージ部の更新

ArgoCDにて以下実施

1. GitLabのマニフェストファイルの監視
2. 更新があれば自動で適用する

Github + CircleCI + ArgoCDの場合であれば、CircleCIが出しているこちらの記事が参考になるかと思います。
https://circleci.com/ja/blog/gitops-argocd/